# Memory Usage in ASP.NET with Multithreading

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, memory, webforms

I have read some articles about multithreading in ASP.NET

but i don't understand what is best... Task, Thread, ThreadPool or Delegate.BeginInvoke.
i have Excel upload button on the Page,
after excel upload is done, data should be validated,
and validation progress should be displayed,
because why validation process runs in new Thread.

here is code example

```
protected void btnValidation_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var excelData = Session["UploadedExcelData"];
    var validator = new DataValidator(excelData);
    validator.Start();
}


public class DataValidator
{
    private readonly IList<IDictionay<String, Object>> excelData;

    public DataValidator(IList<IDictionay<String, Object>> excelData)
    {
        this.excelData = excelData;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var t = new Thread(ValidateData);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void ValidateData()
    {
        //data validation code
    }
}
```

real problem is memory usage on the prodution server,
if validation process runs without Thread then memory usage is about 12GB,
but if validation process runs in new Thread or new Task then memory usage is about 25GB

P.S
i know... use of ThreadPool or Delegate.BeginInvoke for multithreading is bad idea because ASP.NET Page.Requests uses ThreadPool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx?loc=zbtfz_zYFCz&prod=zOtProdz&tech=zOtScenz&lang=zASPNz&prog=zTNMz&type=zMagz&country=zUSz) by Stephan Cleary. In it, he explains the benefit of utilizing the ASP.Net thread pool using Tasks, async/await. What I get out of it, is if it's something that can block your thread pool thread, but is ultimately processed by something else (other server for an API call, database server, disk IO or others), use async so that the thread pool thread goes back to the pool, and other mechanisms, such as an interrupt from a driver, will bubble up the Task completion state.

That said, it sounds like your intense validation code continues to use ASP.Net thread pool threads to process the data. I don't see a benefit to threading/async in this case. Legendary programmer [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has mentioned in Stack Overflow answers and in a [Pluralsight training video](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/skeet-async) that creating new threads uses at least 1 MB of memory on the stack, and to avoid making new threads if you can. I don't know if that lead to your app using a tremendously higher amount of RAM, but I agree with Walther so far.

Now, can your data validation be parallelized? That might be a reason to experiment with asynchrony/threads. The benefit here is to validate faster. See the [Parallel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, you seem to be validating an Excel document, so can you validate multiple rows or cells at the same time, within reasonable use of number of threads?

Finally, the only thing in ASP.Net that I know of that can trickle down events, such as the progress of a validation step, without sending multiple requests via AJAX asking how far along things are, is called [ASP.Net Signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr). It is based on WebSockets for server sent events. You might be able to push a progress value down every now and then during validation to keep your UI informed.

Hope at least some of this helps.

Comment: OOOHH YAHHH SignalR is COOOL :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need any asynchronous action in asp.net (validation, lazy loading etc), you should always use AJAX instead. It's as simple as that.

Web is stateless and multithreading isn't really appropriate when you have thousands of people connecting to your site. Also I don't see ANY benefit when using a new thread for the validation. What would be the purpose?? You're creating new threads without any real reason to back it up.

Comment: as i mentioned above i need to display validation progress
because validation process can be Long Running Thread 
also i don't want increase request timeout in Web.Config